# How to get matching word in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I selected a particular word in notepad++ and same will be highlighted in green colour if that word occured in other line, like same how to get that option in sql developer tool. I just googled, it problem still exist. If anyone have idea, let me know.

Comment: Works for me; though, it isn't highlighted in *green* but in *pink*.

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes...pink colour..ok how to get that setting enable?

Comment: Which version of Oracle SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: @APC Using Oracle SQL Developer 4.1

Comment: So, a version that's 6 or 7 years old. Have you considered updating to some more recent? It's free.

Comment: On this PC, SQL Developer is 17.4 and it *works*. As APC said, upgrade.

Comment: @APC Actually i too get that same, but recently i changed some preference setting so that i cant get that text highlighted option now...

Comment: @Littlefoot your version is also almost 3 years old now ;)

Comment: As I said, *on this PC*, @thatjeffsmith :) But OK, makes sense, downloading 20.2 *as we speak*.

Comment: If only i got a nickel for every download :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click the word.

Matching strings will be highlighted.

If you don't like the highlighting color scheme, change it in the preferences.

[image]

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith, for my oracle sql developer windows, all setting as shown in above image are same. But for cases like 1435 and '1435', matching is not happening that is when I double  click on 1435 then '1435' is not getting highlighted. Please help here.

Comment: with the selected word, hit ctrl+F - that should do it

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith, pressing ctrl+F requires extra efforts but yeah it works. Thanks